Upgrading to Spring 3.2 fails due to Nested Jar changes
We have our application running on Spring 3.1 and we have a usecase where we are using WireMock to create a stub server.
Now after upgrading to Spring 3.2.5 my application is not starting.
From the logs it says it is not able to find the jar.
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: nested:/Users/I514807/Work/RefApps/wiremock-stub-server/target/wiremock-stub-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Here I noticed a word called nested before the actual path.
Upon researching a little I found this in the release notes of SpringBoot
I am looking for some help here, so as to know how can I fix this issue.
I have created a sample application to reproduce the error.
https://github.com/GeneralNitin/Spring-WireMock-Issue

Upgrade to a recent version of wiremock. You are using 3.0 which is old and an alpha/bete of it. Use 3.5.4 which is relocated to org.wiremock.

That also doesn't solve the issue, moreover, I'm not sure it my IntelliJ or what, but after upgrading to the latest version of wiremock from the group org.wiremock I'm unable to import the classes as well.

As of now, I am using this prefix private String prefix = "BOOT-INF/classes/";
I want to know what changes I should make to make it work with Spring 3.2

You shouldn't need any changes also the messing around with the prefix is strange as well. I've updated the dependency in your repo without any issue.

This appears to be a longstanding issue already, see this issue and hasn't been really resolved. I agree with the analysis in that issue that the ClasspathFileSource does the wrong things. The fact that you already need some kind of hack/workaround to adapt for the classpath is proof of that.
The issue lists several workarounds/solutions and I personally would opt for the solution that uses Springs resource abstraction to work.
class SpringClasspathResourceFileSource implements FileSource {


    private final String path;

    SpringClasspathResourceFileSource(final String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public URI getUri() {
        return getURI(path);
    }

    @Override
    public FileSource child(final String subDirectoryName) {
        return new SpringClasspathResourceFileSource(appendToPath(subDirectoryName));
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryFile getBinaryFileNamed(final String name) {
        return new BinaryFile(getURI(appendToPath(name)));
    }

    @Override
    public TextFile getTextFileNamed(final String name) {
        return new TextFile(getURI(appendToPath(name)));
    }

    private URI getURI(final String name) {
        try {
            return new ClassPathResource(name).getURI();
        } catch (IOException root) {
            throw new RuntimeException(root);
        }
    }

    private String appendToPath(final String name) {
        return path + "/" + name;
    }

    @Override
    public void createIfNecessary() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    public List<TextFile> listFilesRecursively() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTextFile(final String name, final String contents) {
    }

    @Override
    public void writeBinaryFile(final String name, final byte[] contents) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFile(final String name) {
    }
}

Which basically means you add this class to your code and use the SpringClasspathResourceFileSource instead of the ClasspathFileSource. This will also allow you to remove the hack with the prefix.
@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop", initMethod = "start")
public WireMockServer myAppMock() {
    logger.info("Mock Path: {}", mockPath);
    return new WireMockServer(options().port(8555)
        .fileSource(new SpringClasspathResourceFileSource(mockPath))
        .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)));
}

Next to that I would strongly suggest to upgrade to a newer version of WireMock as well.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4</version>
</dependency>


The version upgrade did work for me as well after some time, seems like there was some issue with my IntelliJ.

I faced similar issue, and after running through a lot of articles I came across this particular discussion, which helped me resolve the issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38636#issuecomment-1837195400
Add these executions in your pom.xml, under spring-boot-maven-plugin:
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <loaderImplementation>CLASSIC</loaderImplementation>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>

